# Unknown error in requisition request, when i make an external request in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I see some questions, but not on answered my doubts. I'm trying to make a request in angular to an external api and it always shows me an error.

sorry guys my english i'm still not very good.

This is the error that appears:

[image]

Here is the code I use to request the external request in the component:

```
    consultaSku(sku: string) {
    if (sku != null && sku !== '') {
        this.pedidosService.consultaSku(sku)
            .subscribe(dados => console.log(dados)
            );
    }
}
```

This is my service:

```
consultaSku(sku: string) {
    // console.log(sku);
    if (sku !== '') {
        return this.http.get(`//bling.com.br/Api/v2/produto/${sku}/json/?apikey=${apikey}`);
    }
    return of({});
}
```

I wanted to make a query as soon as I type a value in the input.

I really appreciate if you help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the request in the rest client (postman, for example)? You may be making the wrong request to the server.

Comment: Yes, I did it in postman and put the request in chrome and it worked, but when I put it in angular and I get this error